# Azure AD B2C SignIn/Signup Flows with Email/Phone Number

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Azure B2C User Flow SignUp/SignIn with Email/Number.
Requirements:

SignUp with Email/Phone:
while signing up when user click for registration its shows already  email/phone number exist but we are looking when user have already have email then it automatically move to login flow.
[image]

SignIn with Email/Phone:
while user click on the signin if user not exist then it automatically navigate to the signup page so user dont need to manuly go for signup
[image]

Forget Password with Email/Phone:
With the Email/Phone number signin/signup flow there is missing the reset password policy to change password and there is only showing the change phone number option.we need to reset the user password
There is missing the Cenel icon on the phone number signup flow.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did reproduce your scenario and found that there is currently no prebuild option or system in user flow of Azure AD B2C that when user try to sign and if it has not already signup will redirect to signup page and vice versa.

Azure AD B2C offers various [sign-up and sign-in options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/sign-in-options) for users of your applications:

I did Configure my Azure AD B2C local accounts to allow sign-up and sign-in with using email address. There are also other ways with username, phone number, or a combination of methods.

[image]

**For Forget Password with Email/Phone enable the self-server password under the properties of your created user flow.**

[image]

Please follow this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEs2V.jpg) for apply for Forget Password with email and attribute which I have set for my userflow.

I have shown the demo how my user flow is working please check this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZXxM.jpg) as well.

I have redirected my webapp to https://vikashgaurav.com/portfolio/ after successful signing.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-up-and-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: no this is not salution of the problem thanks